# eBay notifications are not being received

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to receive notifications for ItemListed from the Ebay API on Production.

I have successfully subscribed to Ebay's notifications although I am not receiving any mail or call to the specified URL upon actions that I surely know have happened.

I logged in to my developers account and set the right URL and email for notifications.

This is the XML code for the subscription:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SetNotificationPreferencesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<!-- Use the Developer portal or the <ApplicationDeliveryPreferences> container to set 
     the Application delivery settings -->
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken></eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
<ApplicationDeliveryPreferences>
   <!--Enter an email address-->
<AlertEmail>mailto://email@email.com</AlertEmail>
<AlertEnable>Enable</AlertEnable>
<ApplicationEnable>Enable</ApplicationEnable>
<ApplicationURL>MYHHTPSURL</ApplicationURL>
<DeviceType>Platform</DeviceType>
<DeliveryURLDetails>
      <DeliveryURL>MYHTTPSURL</DeliveryURL>
      <DeliveryURLName>TEST</DeliveryURLName>
      <Status>Enable</Status>
    </DeliveryURLDetails>
</ApplicationDeliveryPreferences> -->
<!-- Use the UserDeliveryPreferenceArray to enable to the user for various Event -->
<UserDeliveryPreferenceArray>
<NotificationEnable><EventType>ItemListed</EventType>
<EventEnable>Enable</EventEnable>
</NotificationEnable>
</UserDeliveryPreferenceArray>
</SetNotificationPreferencesRequest>
```

I am adding a pastebin link with the GetNotificationPreferences:
https://pastebin.com/JBAnnX8d

To me everything seems completely fine. Anyone can shed some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be helpful to people having this problem in the future. I solved it by 
authenticating to the API through eBay's authnauth system. Weird solution but works.

Comment: I've been stumped on this for weeks. I can't thank you enough for this answer! I have been using OAuth tokens for everything and couldn't get any notifications to work. I switched to Auth'n'Auth and it works!

Comment: [eBay states](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-trad-apis.html#OAuth) that an application has to be whitelisted in order to receive platform notifications set up with OAuth.

Quote: The Platform Notification calls GetNotificationPreferences and SetNotificationPreferences work with OAuth as outlined above, however your application needs to be white listed in order to receive platform notifications. Please contact [Developer Technical Support](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/gs_get-support.html) for details on getting your application white listed.